# passing complex object to a controller action by a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, binding, controller

I have a problem about passing complex object from a form to an action. I'll try to explain better:

I have the following object:

```
public class Owner
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a container, used to group informations. In this way I can pass with no problem all my things to the same view:

```
public class Container
{
    public string dog { get; set; }
    public Owner owner { get; set; }
}
```

So, I have also the following form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dog) 
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.owner.name) 
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.owner.surname) 

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
}
```

When return the container to my controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult action(Container c)
{
 ..........
```

I obtain null value for the owner name and surname but dog string is passed.
I really don't understand..
Why does this happen?
I'm newbie to mvc 4 so thank you for yours answers.

Comment: The code you have shown will work fine and will be bound correctly.

Comment: if there was no view model then I would have tried public ActionResult action(Container c, Owner owner)

Comment: Look at created html and check name of two editor for owner. it should be "owner.name" not just "name"

Comment: If your model is not binding its due to some code you have not shown us.

Comment: @Mir comment should work, Also as Stephen says  the code will work fine unless you have some other code which you have not shown here

Comment: I have the necessity to use just a single parameter for the action. So i should use only the container as parameter.

Comment: Ok, now it works. Thank you all

Comment: @Vito, Please delete the question. This is of no use to anyone.